# Regex: How to match a string that is not following a #&&, but has to follow a &

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to match the String `&abD&eG`
from `abCD#&&abCD&abD&eG`

The general rules are: 
Match a string consisting of alpha that has to follow `&` but NOT `#&&`.
But once the string starts as a single `&` a `#&&` is still considered as part of the match.
Consecutive `&`'s will count as a match.

So some simplified sample strings and matches are:

`#&&abc&abc`
should match: `&abc`

`&abc&abc`
should match: `&abc&abc`

`#&&abc&abc#&&abc`
should match: `&abc#&&abc`

`#&&abc#&&abc`
should match: NO MATCH

`#&&abc`
should match: NO MATCH

`abc#&&`
should match: NO MATCH

`abc`
should match: NO MATCH

`&&abc&abc`
should match: `&&abc&abc`

`&&abc#&&`
should match: `&&abc#&&`

`#&&&&abc`
should match: `&&abc`

`&&abc&abc&&&&`
should match: `&&abc&abc&&&&`

`&&&`
should match: `&&&`

`abc&abc`
should match: `&abc`

I currently have the regex `(?<!#&&)(&\p{Alnum}+)+` but it detects the sequence after `&` regardless of whether or not it is followed by a #&.
How should I modify it so that it will match accordingly to my general rules?

Comment: What do you mean by "match"? Do you mean that the code should print out the matched string?

Comment: Why do you have "?<!"  ?? Looks like the < is errant, "?!" means no match.

Comment: @Keara I'm using a Pattern object and a Matcher object.

Comment: @user1676075 ?<! is a negative look-behind. That's where I'm having trouble on.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have rephrased the question to be more specific to my case

Comment: What you ask for is [`(?<!#&)(?:&\p{Alnum}+)+`](https://regex101.com/r/HjcvY4/1) and it does not work for your test cases.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Right. The regex I have provided does not work. Is there another regex I can use?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Match a string consisting of alpha that has to follow & but NOT #&&. But once the string starts as a single & a #&& is still considered as part of the match. Consecutive &'s will count as a match.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What don't you still understand and want me to clarify? I have the wrong regex, yes I am aware. I would like to change my regex, but what should I change it to?? I'm having trouble coming up with the correct regex.

Comment: Please post any relevant code you have so far, and what output you get from it.

Comment: @Keara No code is needed for this assignment. It is using just one single regex. I'm currently using this site to test the regex. The reason why I mentioned java was because of the syntax and style. http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/

Answer (score 0):

I tried building a regex for this but as the `&` is part of both, the marker to exclude a match, and also a character to be included in the match, it got extra complicated, for something that easily can be detected with a simple FDA.

I am leaving here the algorithm if it is of any use for you. It is implemented in java, but porting it other languages shouldn't be a problem.

The `match` method returns an `ArrayList` with three values:

1. "true" if there was a match or "false" otherwise
2. The position in the string where the match starts, or -1 if there is no match
3. The matched string.

   ```
   public class SO47732442 {

       private int [] [] states = {
           {1,4,0},
           {3,2,3},
           {3,0,3},
           {3,3,3},
           {3,3,3}
       };

       private int state = 0;

       private int getCol(char c){
           int rtn = 4;
           switch(c){
           case '#':
               rtn = 0; break;
           case '&':
               rtn = 1; break;
           default:
               rtn = 2;
           }
           return rtn;
       }

       public ArrayList<String> match(String text){
           state = 0;
           ArrayList<String> rtn = new ArrayList<>();
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           int start = -1;
           boolean match = false;
           for(int i=0; i<text.length();i++){
               int col = getCol(text.charAt(i));
               state = states[state][col];
               if(state == 3){
                   if(!match){
                       sb.append("&");
                       start = i;
                       match = true;
                   }
                   sb.append(text.charAt(i));
               }
           }
           rtn.add(match? "true" : "false");
           rtn.add(""+start);
           rtn.add(sb.toString());
           return rtn;
       }


       /* This is just to test the matches */
       public static void main(String[] args){
           SO47732442 app = new SO47732442();
           ArrayList<String> tests = new ArrayList<>();

           tests.add("#&&abc&abc");
           tests.add("&abc&abc");
           tests.add("#&&abc&abc#&&abc");
           tests.add("#&&abc#&&abc");
           tests.add("#&&abc");
           tests.add("abc#&&");
           tests.add("abc");
           tests.add("&&abc&abc ");
           tests.add("&&abc#&&");
           tests.add("#&&&&abc");
           tests.add("&&abc&abc&&&&");
           tests.add("&&&");
           tests.add("abc&abc");
           tests.add("abcabc&");


           for(String test : tests){
               System.out.println("Text: " + test);
               ArrayList<String> result = app.match(test);

               for(String res : result){
                   System.out.println(res);
               }
               System.out.println("");
           }

       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Can't get a regex to work, but here's a function that passes all your test cases (probably can be cleaned up a little):

```
public static String getMatch(String string) {
    int startIndex = 0;

while (string.indexOf("&", startIndex) > string.indexOf("#&&", startIndex))
{
    if (string.indexOf("&", startIndex) < 0) return "";
    if (string.indexOf("#&&", startIndex) < 0) return string.substring(string.indexOf("&", startIndex));

    startIndex = string.indexOf("#&&", startIndex) + 3;
}
return (string.indexOf("&", startIndex) < 0) ? "" : string.substring(string.indexOf("&", startIndex));
```

}